# Add a local branch but need the origin is also set ( SmartGIT )

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch, smartgit

Hi i am a beginner for SmartGIT  , I want to create a local branch and that same branch name should be in the origin list .

Ex : -

Currently i have

```
Local Branches (2)

develop = origin
master = origin


origin (2)

develop
master
```

I want to add a project "MyPro" to Local branches but i want this to be set in the origin also , first it will be taken from the origin -> develop .

So the final result would be like this

```
Local Branches (3)

develop = origin
master = origin
MyPro = origin


origin (3)

develop
master
MyPro
```

So i can work in local `MyPro` and commit to the remote `MyPro` and later merge remote `MyPro` in to the remote develop branch .

I have tried few things , one is

- write click Local branches . add a branch .
- Then set the remote tracked branch to origin develop .

But nothing creates me a  `MyPro` in origin  ,

I also tried to go to origin and create a branch named `MyPro` and checkout from origin -> develop . but that is also not possible .

I know this is very simple , but i am really unable to do this .

Please help , Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use **Branch|Add Branch** to create your local `MyPro`branch (core Git will know it as `refs/heads/MyPro`). Make sure you will confirm this dialog with **Add Branch & Checkout**, so SmartGit will put you into your new branch immediately.

Now have a couple of commits.

Finally, use **Remote|Push** to push your new branch to `origin` and once asked by SmartGit, select to **Configure** tracking. This will create `origin/MyPro` (core Git will know it as `refs/remotes/origin/MyPro`).